# Justifying the result from Finding Expert System

Tags: analysis

I am a student and working term project in topic "Finding Expert System" 
using database from stackoverflow (September,2009) to find the list of experts for each tag.
Please help me to justify the result from my system in these tags: "JAVA","PHP","HTML","groovy" and "XML" 
Are these users appropriate to be an expert for these tags or not?

-------------------JAVA--------------------

1   Jon Skeet
2   cletus
3   Tom Hawtin

4   Gumbo
5   Greg
6   Pascal MARTIN
7   karim79
8   VonC
9   Brian Agnew

10  Paolo Bergantino

-------------------PHP--------------------

1   Jon Skeet
2   cletus
3   Gumbo
4   Greg
5   Pascal MARTIN
6   karim79
7   VonC
8   Brian Agnew

9   Paolo Bergantino
10  nickf

-------------------HTML--------------------

1   Jon Skeet
2   cletus
3   Tom Hawtin

4   Gumbo
5   Greg
6   Pascal MARTIN
7   karim79
8   VonC
9   Brian Agnew

10  Paolo Bergantino

-------------------groovy--------------------

1   Jon Skeet
2   cletus
3   Tom Hawtin

4   VonC
5   duffymo

6   Michael Borgwardt
7   dfa

8   mmyers
9   Robert Harvey
10  coobird

-------------------XML--------------------

1   Jon Skeet
2   cletus
3   Tom Hawtin

4   Gumbo
5   Greg
6   Pascal MARTIN
7   karim79
8   VonC
9   Brian Agnew

10  Paolo Bergantino

Comment: as in always the case:
1) tag with homework
2) list what you've tried so far

Comment: I'm glad I'm not an expert in PHP, but I've knowingly written a line of Groovy, have only a basic knowledge of HTML and wouldn't consider myself anywhere near an XML expert.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like  you've just pulled the top reputed members who have posted in each tag.  Perhaps a better way to do it would be look at the amount of reputation *gained in a tag* by each member.

In the same way the tag badges are awarded. The results might still end up similar simply because the top ten users have so much more reputation than anyone else, but it might be a more accurate listing.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering on the grounds that hopefully it'll be moved to Meta soon.)

It would be somewhat reasonable to classify me as an expert in Java. Groovy is more debatable - I'm a contributor to Groovy in Action, but don't use Groovy regularly. I'm reasonable on XML handling *in .NET* but I wouldn't say I'm an expert. Calling me an expert in PHP and HTML is laughable I'm afraid.